# On Android Studio, View and Override are not being recognized. I am also not receiving error messages when typing gibberish as well

Tags: android

Here is my example below:

I do not get any error message for this code and nothing comes up for View

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
public void clickFunction(View)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    adlfjadskjfodkljaodsjldk

            eads;frewkqipjdafslkfjdslkjfdoash jla


}
```

}

Comment: Sorry, I was on powersave mode!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the braces for the function clickFunction, plus a name for the argument of said function (clickFunction), here is how it should look like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 public void clickFunction(View view){}
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }
}
```